# "Input/output error" when trying to access Windows directory from within Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, nautilus, windows-10

I have Windows 10 and Ubuntu 17.10 installed together as a dual-boot system. When I try to copy files from the Windows 10 system directory I encounter this error:

[image: Input/Output Error]

I am pretty sure that Windows runs normally – I can read the files under Windows 10. And I am also sure that the files are not corrupted, since if I use `ls` in the terminal, I can get the output as expected:

[image: Listing the content of the "Windows" directory in Terminal]

I can also open any subdirectories of the "Windows" directory using nautilus, by using `cd` to navigate to that directory first, then using `nautilus .`.

Only the "Windows" directory can not be opened in nautilus. What can I do to resolve this error?

Comment: Check the output of `dmesg` for more detailed error messages.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to [Yashas' answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/989097/301745):

To get Windows to shut down fully -- bypassing Fast Shutdown, hibernation, and anything else -- you don't need to permanently change the power settings, just reboot to the Windows login screen, click the power button ⏻, then click **Shut down** while holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>. Then you can access the folders from Ubuntu. Note this may be only temporary, until the next time you use Windows.