# Cannot open Windows 10 folder

Tags: windows, password, file-sharing

I am trying to reset my forgotten MSI windows 10 local password using Ubuntu and when I am trying to access Windows 10 installation folder to locate the Windows/System32/config I get

> this location could not be displayed
>   input/output error

I've searched for it online but I could not find a solution. The error I get is this:

[image]

Comment: Can you access `C:\Windows\System32`? If not, what about the root of the C drive?

Comment: @wjandrea Thank you for your quick reply. No, im getting the error as soon as I am trying to access the "Windows" folder. I am a newbie at this so where can I find the root of the C drive? This is the point im stucked if it helps https://imgur.com/yqnwocL

Comment: You're at the root of the C drive in that screenshot. Please post the whole error message. You can [edit] your question to add it.

Comment: @wjandrea done, posted a screenhsot

Comment: What happens when you click "OK"?

Comment: @wjandrea the folder appears as empty, althouth it is not empty

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Input/output error" when trying to access Windows directory from within Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/989054/input-output-error-when-trying-to-access-windows-directory-from-within-ubuntu). I just wrote an answer specifically for your situation.

Comment: @wjandrea I tried it, still getting the same error

Comment: OK. This might be a hardware issue then. Try checking the [SMART status](https://askubuntu.com/q/528072/301745).

Answer (score 0):

Enter in terminal:

```
sudo chmod -R 775 /media/ubuntu/Windows/Windows/System32/config
```

Then use:

```
chntpw
```